# Straighten barcodes from rough surface

Tags: decode, barcode

How can I straighten the barcode from the rough surface?
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j231b.jpg)

Comment: What is your goal ? Just to decode the barcode ? If so, it all depends on the decoding library, and choosing the right one can make a big difference. Getting your image straight and flat and deskewed is perhaps a bigger task than you think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My goal just to decode the barcode, can you recommend the library or paper to decode the barcode on crumpled paper.

Comment: I will not post this as an answer, as StackOverflow should not be a link farm. In my personal experience, the scanner application for phone from CodeCorporation beats every other in scanning ability. [An SDK is available](https://www.codecorp.com/products/embedded-sdk), which you may try. Notice that I do not have experience using it myself.